How to Invoke complete CLI onto the GUI Output text Box using C# (.NET Framework)
I Have done CLI invoking to my program, by these lines of codes
Invoke((Action)(() => textBoxOutput.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + e.Data)))
I am getting output on my GUI Output text Box, But it is not user interactive, if it finds a Question, it will take input automatically and go onto next line.
So, i am looking for solution where I can modify it properly so that it takes user input (For required questioned) and then it goes further.
I tried with flags like,
   {
        continueProcessingOutput = false;
        Invoke((Action)(() => 
        {
             string userInput = PromptUserForInput(e.Data);
             process.StandardInput.WriteLine(userInput);
             continueProcessingOutput = true; // Resume processing output
         }));
         // Pause reading the output to wait for user input
         process.CancelOutputRead();

         // Prompt user for input on the UI thread
         var userInput = await Task.Run(() => PromptUserForInput(e.Data));
         rocess.StandardInput.WriteLine(userInput);

         // Resume reading the output
         process.BeginOutputReadLine();```




"if it finds a Question" what does that mean here what Questions are you talking about? I "I tried with flags like"  same here what do you mean by with flags here? "But it is not user interactive" you want to add text to a textbox what should be interactive about that?

I dont want to add text, I am invoking output of CLI onto my textbox. So If I try to invoke Complete CLI output onto my textbox, there are some missing execution lines because those lines contain some questions, which requires users to give input as Yes or No. I am unable to invoke those onto my Output textbox.
